# Permission denied problem when executing

Tags: bash, permissions

Trying to launch VisualWorks launcher.

```
robert@robert-System-Product-Name:~$ /root/vw8.1.1pul/bin/linuxx86_64/vwlinuxx86_64 "~/VisualWorks Projects/launchpad64.im"
bash: /root/vw8.1.1pul/bin/linuxx86_64/vwlinuxx86_64: Permission denied
robert@robert-System-Product-Name:~$
```

The permissions for the executable are:

```
root@robert-System-Product-Name:~/vw8.1.1pul/bin/linuxx86_64# ls -l vwlinuxx86_64
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 2589710 Jun 16 06:32 vwlinuxx86_64
root@robert-System-Product-Name:~/vw8.1.1pul/bin/linuxx86_64#
```

The permissions for the argument are:

```
robert@robert-System-Product-Name:~/VisualWorks Projects$ ls -l
total 23788
-rwxrwxr-x 1 robert robert 24355496 Jun 16 06:31 launchpad64.im
robert@robert-System-Product-Name:~/VisualWorks Projects$
```

I thought that `r-xr-xr-x` in permissions meant that the owner, group, and everybody can execute a file. Apparently bash thinks otherwise.

Help!

Comment: Maybe it's permissions/mount options on intervening directories. Check with my `pathlld` script `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git` - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?"

Comment: Try chmod 777 filename.type

Comment: The `/root` directory has 700 permissions and is owned by root, you need to be root to access/open any file under `/root`, but you ran the command as robert.

Comment: I added execute permission to /root (chmod +x root) and it now runs. I know that the installer should never have placed the application in /root, but that is what it does. The application actually runs and I was even able to create a launcher for it.

Comment: Where should I really place the application to follow Ubuntu best practices?

Comment: It turns out that the app installation program puts the app in the wrong directory by default. Reinstalling and specifying a different directory solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that VisualWorks typically installs the files in the wrong directory (/). You must use the custom install to force VisualWorks to install in a directory of your choosing.